How can I find out how compatible a quantum circuit is to a backend without executing the circuit
Say I have multiple backends, I need a score to determine how well a backend is suitable for that particular circuit, I have it's noise model too, I tried transpiling the circuit and calculating noise estimate through the exact gate errors and readout errors, but doesn't seem to work that well.
